# Converting hexadecimal (A-F) numbers

Tags: excel, vba

I made a function to convert numbers. e.g. base 5 to base 15 - meaning other types than the basic 2, 8, 10, 16. They are based on converting the number to base 10 (by using powers) and then from base 10 to other base (mod, div).

There is an issue inputting values A-F (hexadecimal is the top).

This is a separate part of code which converts the number to base 10.

```
Function prevdeset(base As Integer, ipt As String) As String
Dim x As Integer
Dim s As Integer
Dim u As Integer
Dim p As Integer
c = Str(ipt)
x = Len(ipt)
u = 0
For i = x To 1 Step -1
    If Mid(c, i, 1) = "A" Then
        p = 10
    ElseIf Mid(c, i, 1) = "B" Then
        p = 11
    ElseIf Mid(c, i, 1) = "C" Then
        p = 12
    ElseIf Mid(c, i, 1) = "D" Then
        p = 13
    ElseIf Mid(c, i, 1) = "E" Then
        p = 14
    ElseIf Mid(c, i, 1) = "F" Then
        p = 15
    Else: p = Val(Mid(c, i, 1))
    End If
    p = p * (base ^ (x - i))
    u = u + p
Next i
prevdeset = u
End Function
```

The function selects i-th character from the right and first checks if the string value is A - if not, then B, C, D, E, F, and if none of those, it should convert the character to a number (I don't try to input other letters as G, H..).

There is no issue with the output if the input is not a string, and the full code (not shown here) can output letters (example: 10 in base 10 will be A in base 14).

Comment: "...there seems to be an issue..." what kind of issue? Have you tried stepping through the code? Does an error occur, and if so, on what line?

Comment: Step through the code line by line (F8) and check the values of all variables (mouseover). If you find a variable that does not contain the value you are expecting (and this will be the case, based on your description) then focus on that line. That is probably where the error is. Update your question with your findings.

Comment: You might benefit from reading 
[Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/284237/3219613)

Comment: Get rid of the `c = Str(ipt)`- statement. The idea of `Str` converts a number to a string, but you are expecting `ipt` to be a string already, so no need to do a conversion.

Comment: Your 14-line nested `if` statement can be replaced by the single line `p = Val("&H"&Mid(c, i, 1))` The point is that `Val` can *already* handle hex literals (which begin with &H in VBA), so why reinvent the wheel?

Answer (score 1):

You're getting an overflow error due to the `VBA` limit on `Integers`. Change your variables to `Long` and your code works

```
| Type    | Storage | Range of Values                 |
|---------|---------|---------------------------------|
| Byte    | 1 byte  | 0 to 255                        |
| Integer | 2 bytes | -32,768 to 32,767               |
| Long    | 4 bytes | -2,147,483,648 to 2,147,483,647 |
```

---

```
Option Explicit
Function prevdeset(base As Integer, ipt As String) As String
    Dim x As Long, s As Long, u As Long, p As Long
    Dim i As Long
    Dim c As String

    c = ipt
    x = Len(ipt)
    u = 0
    For i = x To 1 Step -1
        If Mid(c, i, 1) = "A" Then
        p = 10
        ElseIf Mid(c, i, 1) = "B" Then
        p = 11
        ElseIf Mid(c, i, 1) = "C" Then
        p = 12
        ElseIf Mid(c, i, 1) = "D" Then
        p = 13
        ElseIf Mid(c, i, 1) = "E" Then
        p = 14
        ElseIf Mid(c, i, 1) = "F" Then
        p = 15
        Else: p = Val(Mid(c, i, 1))
        End If
        p = p * (base ^ (x - i))
        u = u + p
    Next i
    prevdeset = u
End Function

Sub test()
    Dim HexVal As String
    HexVal = "7B19AB"

    Debug.Print CLng("&H" & HexVal)
    Debug.Print prevdeset(16, HexVal)
End Sub
```

Also, you don't need to convert your `ipt` to `String` - you've already declared `ipt` as a `String`. You could enforce `c` to be a string though by simply declaring it (you should always declare all of your variables a handy habit to encforce this practice is to ensure all of your modules have `Option Explicit` at the top).

In fact your code could be shortened to:

```
Function prevdeset(base As Integer, ipt As String) As String
    Dim i As Long, u As Long
    Dim p As Long
    Dim HexCode As String

    For i = Len(ipt) To 1 Step -1
        HexCode = UCase(Mid(ipt, i, 1))

        If Not IsNumeric(HexCode) Then
            p = Asc(HexCode) - Asc("A") + 10
            If p >= base Then Err.Raise Number:=999, Source:="prevdeset", Description:="Invalid Hex"
        Else
            p = Val(HexCode)
        End If

        p = p * (base ^ (Len(ipt) - i))
        u = u + p
    Next i
    prevdeset = u
End Function
```

Comment: You shouldn't link this function to `Excel` as you do with your trick to use `Range`. To convert a letter to it's value, use something like `p = Asc(HexCode) - Asc("A") + 10`. And when checking the validity, use `If p >= base  Then Err.Raise...`

Comment: @FunThomas Fair point - thanks for the suggestion have updated

Answer (score 0):

The code below is a simplified and corrected version of yours. The reason why your code didn't work is in the use of integers instead of, at least, long. I am suggesting LongPtr.

```
Function Prevdeset(ByVal base As Integer, ByVal ipt As String) As LongPtr
    ' pass the arguments ByVal to avoid having them changed by the code
    ' in this way you wouldn't need the variable ipt
    ' Add Option Explicit at the top of your code module
    ' to ensure that you don't forget to declare variables

    Dim u As LongPtr
    Dim p As Integer
    Dim x As Integer
    Dim i As Integer
    ' the Dim statement sets all values to 0

    x = Len(ipt)
    For i = x To 1 Step -1
        p = InStr("0123456789ABCDEF", Mid(ipt, i, 1)) - 1
        If p < 0 Then
            MsgBox "invalid characer " & Mid(ipt, i, 1) & "." & vbCr & _
                   "The returned result may not be correct."
        End If

        u = u + (p * (base ^ (x - i)))
    Next i
    Prevdeset = u
End Function
```

Note that the function's return type must be the same as assigned to the variable `u` (LongPtr in my code, but at least Long). If you wish the function to return a string you might assign `Prevdeset = CStr(u)` at the function's last line of code.

Comment: Should be noted `LongPtr` will only be different compared to `Long` on a 64-bit system. `LongPtr` is converted to `Long` on a 32-bit system and `LongLong` on a 64-bit